# Laravel 9 with wordpress in subdirectory

Tags: laravel, wordpress

I have a laravel 9 project. now I need to add wordpress to subdirectory like

```
laravel
--app
--config
--blog <- wordpress project
```

and URL will:

```
laravel.project  <-- laravel site
laravel.project/blog <-- wordpress site
```

web deploy to sharehosting so I can't config apache or nginx...

How can do it by .htaccess file? Thanks

I create .htaccess on root laravel folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond $1 !^(blog)
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

but only show homepage of blog. and any page like blog/wp-admin... has Error forbidden

Comment: set APP_URL= laravel.project in .env, hopefully i will helps you

Comment: Thank for comment. my laravel work fine. I had problem with run wp